# Get full date of the Monday of the current week in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have looked all over the internet and have found what I believe is outdated ways to go about this. I have the latest version of SQL and I just want to know how to get the date of the Monday of the current week via query.

Comment: You should edit your question and include the "outdated" ways.  You'll probably just get the same old answers back if you don't.

Comment: Latest version of SQL? And MySQL? Is the ANSI SQL 2015 draft official standard now, or is it still SQL-2011?

Comment: Why use SQL for this?

Comment: SELECT DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,CURDATE()), 0) MondayOfCurrentWeek; returns - Error Code: 1582
Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATEDIFF'

Comment: Sorry  - MYSQL version 5.1.73

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simplest way is `weekday()`:

```
select curdate() - interval weekday(curdate()) day;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/71145) is a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. This is the error I received: Error Code: 1582
Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATEDIFF'

Comment: Given that this answer does not use the function `datediff()`, that seems like a very unlikely error.

Comment: My bad had an old copy lol, this is the real error: Error Code: 1582
Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'weekday'

Comment: @MikeValentino  . . . It is all fixed.